# function defined in one file not found when calling from other file

Tags: python

Im using win32 functions with ctypes.
I put all the declartions in one file (`wrapper`) and use them in `main` file.
Why am I getting the `error` that function is not defined?
If I put the declartions in main file everything works as expected.
Both files are in the same directory.

**wrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

# Create ctypes wrapper for Win32 functions we need, with correct argument/return types
_CreateMutex = windll.kernel32.CreateMutexA
_CreateMutex.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.LPCSTR]
_CreateMutex.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
```

**main.py**

```
import wrapper
_CreateMutex(...)
```

**ERROR:**

```
NameError: name '_CreateMutex' is not defined
```

Comment: But this is basic Python; you either need to import `_CreateMutex` directly, or reference it as `wrapper._CreateMutex`. I'd suggest you do an introductory python tutorial before moving onto complex things like ctypes

Comment: my bad, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two solutions:

```
import wrapper
wrapper._CreateMutex()
```

or

```
from wrapper import _CreateMutex
_CreateMutex()
```

Without going into much details (maybe read https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html ?)

```
import wrapper
```

adds "wrapper" to your current namespace - and nothing more, so name _CreateMutex() does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

as you imported wrapper.py then you should use:
`

```
import wrapper
wrapper._CreateMutex(...)`
```